# how to set bottom of inline-block element at the bottom of block element

Tags: html, css

suppose i have following html and css code:

```css
.something{
  width: 200px;
}
.display-block {
  display: block;
}
.req-field{
  float: right;
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="something">
  <span class="display-block">First name:<span class="req-field">required</span></span></div>
```

as you can see that 'required' text is floating up compared to 'first name'. if i want 'required' text too have bottom to touch the bottom of display-block span

Comment: When you float an element you are removing it from the natural flow of the DOM so using vertical-align won't work IIRC

Comment: so how can we work to get it done ?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py's answer works

Comment: @Billy yes i am familiar with absolute positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `line-height` to adjust the height.

```css
.something {
    width: 200px;
}
.display-block {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.req-field {
    float: right;
    font-size: 9px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 29px;
}
```

```html
<div class="something">
  <span class="display-block">First name:<span class="req-field">required</span></span></div>
```

Comment: it came down a bit, but not touching the base

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - You need to set the `height` and `line-height` to `20px`

Comment: i did set the height and line-height to 20px

Comment: you please check your own code snippet, required text came down a bit, but not touching the base

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - On my screen it is touching the base like you said in your main post "_i want 'required' text too have bottom to touch the bottom of display-block span_"

Comment: if my font size of "first name" is set to 18px(suppose) and of "required" to be 9px, now what should be the height value ?

Comment: The `height` should be `11px` and the `line-height` as well. -----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0r6nz4qm/) (**Note**: I've removed `float: right` to show you that the text aligns properly.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65661/discussion-between-edward-torvalds-and-chipchocolate-py).